# Fine the value of the polynomial specified at x=n+1

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $p (x) $be a polynomial of degree $n $ such that 
$p (k)=(k)/(k+1)$ for all $k=0,1,2,...,n$.
find the value of $p (n+1)$.

I have tried to find the value for specific values of $n $ but I don't know how to solve for the general case. 
kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the polynomial $(x+1)p(x)-x$ it is of degree $n+1$ and it has roots $0,1,2\ldots,n$. Hence
$$(x+1)p(x)-x=ax(x-1)(x-2)\cdots (x-n)$$
Put $x=-1$ to get
$$1=a(-1)(-2)\cdots (-n-1) = a(n+1)!(-1)^{n+1} \implies a= \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$
Thus if $x=n+1$
$$(n+2)p(n+1)-(n+1)=a(n+1)!$$
Hence
$$p(n+1)=\frac{(n+1)+a(n+1)!}{n+2}=\frac{(n+1)+(-1)^{n+1}}{n+2}$$